# How can I display the virtualKeybord under every textField on QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtvirtualkeyboard

I have a virtualKeyboard it's always in the bottom of the parent I need something more flexible, to make the virtual keybored sticky to the textField?

I try to change the x, y but it's not work for me